# MS Visual Basic how to sort 1 array and return index for second array?

Tags: sorting, vba, excel, indexing

the language I am looking is MS Visual Basic.

How can I sort an array and change other arrays accordingly (using an index?)
I was searching, but couldnt find any stuff on that. Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

e.g. Sort array BirthArray and change the order of Array1 and ID accordingly?

```
Array1 = 'John', 'Christina','Mary', 'frediric', 'Johnny','billy','mariah'

BirthArray = 1998, 1923, 1983,1982,1924,1923,1954

ID = 12312321, 1231231209, 123123, 234324, 23423, 2234234,932423

Dim Array() As String

Dim BirthArray() As Integer

Dim ID() As Integer
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry but why wouldn't you just use a 2 dimension array and sort it once?

Comment: This page on [cpearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CollectionsAndDictionaries.htm) may be of some help

Comment: Hi, there shall be three dimensions already and I want to add more lists / attributes later on.

Comment: I agree with Jesse. You can use a `Redim Preserve` to add further width to your dataset later on as needed

Answer (score 3):

You should make a class to hold the values, put a collection of the classes into a List,  then sort the the list using a lambda expression:

```
Public Class Info
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property BirthYear As Integer
    Public Property ID As Integer

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(sName As String, wBirthYear As Integer, wID As Integer)
        Me.New
        Me.Name = sName
        Me.BirthYear = wBirthYear
        Me.ID = wID
    End Sub
End Class

Public Sub DoSort()
    Dim cRecords As New System.Generic.List(Of Info)

    cRecords.Add(New Info('John', 1998, 12312321)
    ' ToDo: Add more records

    cRecords.Sort(
    Function (ByVal oItem1 As Info, ByVal oItem2 As Info) 
       Return oItem2.BirthYear.CompareTo(oItem1.BirthYear)
    End Function)

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your quick answer!
Is there no easier way and I have to add a class? Performance doesnt matter in the program for me.
For the class I wonder which part has to go into the Class Module and which part into the module. I looked on some information on classes. Well, I guess you are right in that I have to use and to learn to deal with classes?! Would you be so kind and could you tell me exactly how to add one class in VBA-Excel? I stil found the code not working and suppose it shouldnt. It would be nice, if you could review the code again, if it doesnt cost you too much time.
R

Answer (score 1):

The proposed soluton below (based on your VBA tag).

1. creates a 2D array from 3 single arrays (as suggested by Jesse)
2. uses `Redim Preserve` to add a fourth dataset *"NewData"* to a 2D array *"ArrayMaster"*
3. creates a temporary worksheet, dumps *"ArrayMaster"* to it, sorts by *"Newdata"* (ascending order) to create a sorted array, *"ArrayMaster2"*
4. deletes the working sheet

Excel is very efficient at sorting, so this method provided an easy and quick way for a sort (or multi level sort)

You could use a [bubble sort](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=103) technique if Excel wasn't available for the sheet dump/sort

```
Option Base 1
Sub ComboArray()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Array1()
Dim Birthday()
Dim ID()
Dim NewData()
Dim ArrayMaster()
Dim ArrayMaster2()
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCalc As Long
Dim lngCheck As Long

Birthday = Array(1998, 1923, 1983, 1982, 1924, 1923, 1954)
Array1 = Array("John", "Christina", "Mary", "frediric", "Johnny", "billy", "mariah")
ID = Array(12312321, 1231231209, 123123, 234324, 23423, 2234234, 932423)
ReDim ArrayMaster(1 To UBound(Array1, 1), 1 To 3)

'Create 2D MasterArray
For lngRow = 1 To UBound(Array1, 1)
    ArrayMaster(lngRow, 1) = Array1(lngRow)
    ArrayMaster(lngRow, 2) = Birthday(lngRow)
    ArrayMaster(lngRow, 3) = ID(lngRow)
Next

NewData = Array(1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6)

'Check if new field is longer than overall array
If UBound(NewData, 1) > UBound(ArrayMaster, 1) Then
lngCheck = MsgBox("New field exceeds current array size, proceeding will drop off excess records" & vbNewLine & "(Press Cancel to end code)", vbOKCancel, "Do you want to proceed?")
If lngCheck = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
End If

'Add NewData field
ReDim Preserve ArrayMaster(UBound(ArrayMaster, 1), UBound(ArrayMaster, 2) + 1)
For lngRow = 1 To UBound(NewData, 1)
    ArrayMaster(lngRow, UBound(ArrayMaster, 2)) = NewData(lngRow)
Next
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    lngCalc = .Calculation
End With

'Create working sheet, dump MasterArray and sort by Newdata (position 4 = cell D1)
Set ws = Worksheets.Add
ws.[a1].Resize(UBound(ArrayMaster, 1), UBound(ArrayMaster, 2)).Value2 = ArrayMaster
ws.UsedRange.Sort ws.[d1], xlAscending
'Create our sorted array MasterArray2, now with NewData(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
ArrayMaster2 = ws.[a1].Resize(UBound(ArrayMaster, 1), UBound(ArrayMaster, 2)).Value2
ws.Delete

'cleanup working sheet
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .Calculation = lngCalc
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: great thanks! I will use this method for my sorting tasks!
As I said it is not relevant for me the time it takes to run through it. Just in "ArrayMaster(lngRow, UBound(ArrayMaster, 2) + 1) = NewData(lngRow)" I I found the +1 needs gives an out of bounds-error after I implemented it.
Thank you guys for your responses, I'm sure it will be of help for others as well

Comment: @user1113953 no probs. I have fixed the offending line to `ArrayMaster(lngRow, UBound(ArrayMaster, 2)) = NewData(lngRow)` - this was a poor early edit on my behalf. The +1 having being copied from the earlier redim.

Comment: btw, welcome to stackoverflow, if this answer fits you, please accept it by clicking on the tick on the left of the answer - see meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/… for more information